# How to find the last numeric value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to get the last numeric value in column y and set that value to the same row in `prev_numeric_value`. Here is my current code:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
mydata = {'x' : [10, 50, 18, 32, 47, 20], 'y' : ['12', 'N/A', 'N/A', '13', 'N/A', '16']}
    
df=pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df['prev_numeric_value']=''

#    out: 
#    x    y prev_numeric_value
#    0  10   12                   
#    1  50  N/A                   
#    2  18  N/A                   
#    3  32   13                   
#    4  47  N/A                   
#    5  20   16
```

My desired output should look like:

```py
#    x   y   prev_numeric_value
#    0  10   12                  12
#    1  50  N/A                  12
#    2  18  N/A                  12
#    3  32   13                  13
#    4  47  N/A                  13
#    5  20   16                  16
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `ffill()`:

```
df['prev_val'] = df['y'].where(df['y'].ne('N/A') ).ffill()
```

Output:

```
    x    y prev_val
0  10   12       12
1  50  N/A       12
2  18  N/A       12
3  32   13       13
4  47  N/A       13
5  20   16       16
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!